# Query or command to find a Document, given an ObjectID but NOT a collection

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

So I have a document that has references to foreign ObjectIDs that may point to other documents or collections.

For example this is the pseudo-structure of the document

```
{
    _id: ObjectID(xxxxxxxx),
    ....
    reference: ObjectID(yyyyyyyy)

}
```

I can't find anything that does not involve providing the collection and given that I don't know for sure on which collection to search, I am wondering if there is a way for me to find the document in the entire database and find the collection ObjectID(yyyyyyyy) belongs to.

Comment: I'd strongly suggest you consider an alternative schema design.  You can't do this type of query efficiently in MongoDb unless you move all documents into a single collection.

Comment: Unfortunately that is out of my hands, that is on my clients side and they decided for a schema to avoid data inconsistencies. I was hoping that there was something built in like Google's ndb but Seems like I'll have then to crawl all collections. Thanks

Comment: Might want to tell your clients that this is not how MongoDB works. It's not a RDBMS.

Answer (score 1):

The only possible way to do this is by listing every collection in the database and performing a `db.collection.find()` on each one.

E.g. in the Mongo shell I would do something like

```
var result = new Array();
var collections = db.getCollectionNames();

for (var i = 0; i < collections.length; i++) {
    var found = db.getCollection(collections[i]).findOne({ "_id" : ObjectId("yyyyyyyy") });
    if (found) {
        result.push(found);
    }
}

print(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to run your query on all collections in your database.

```
db.getCollectionNames().forEach(function(collection){
    db[collection].find({ $or : [ 
                            { _id : ObjectId("535372b537e6210c53005ee5") },
                            { reference : ObjectId("535372b537e6210c53005ee5")}]
    }).forEach(printjson);
});
```